# Apply Computation And Return As Another Row Without Union

Tags: sql, sql-server, row

For example, my table data looks like this:

```
       ID  intValue  date
       1   5         1/1/1
       1   10        22/22/22
```

What I want to do is multiply the `intValue` column by 5, 10, and 15 for each instance of intValue.

So my result set would like like:

```
       ID  intValue  date
       1   25         1/1/1
       1   50         1/1/1
       1   75         1/1/1
       1   50         22/22/22
       1   100        22/22/22
       1   150        22/22/22
```

How would I get a result set like this?

**SOLUTION**

[qxg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23636393/1504882) below most accurately answered how to best handle the question above. Another way to manipulate the data, and the method by which I used it was:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CrossTable.Value = 5 THEN 'By Five!' 
WHEN CrossTable.Value = 10 Then 'By Ten!'
WHEN CrossTable.Value = 15 Then 'By Fifteen!' END AS ByWhat,
CrossTable.Value As Base Value,
intValue * CrossTable.Value
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (5), (10), (15)) CrossTAble(Value)
```

Comment: Why are you excluding a union query?

Comment: Is the fact that you want to multiply by 5, 10, and 15 anything to do with the fact that the two rows you have there are 5 and 10? Or will it always be 5, 10, and 15?

Comment: @DanBracuk the query is much more complex than what this question required, and a union is overkill.

Comment: @AakashM The numbers are irrelevant, and will actually be decimal values, I just wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: Minus 1 for asking for something other than what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leverage CROSS JOIN and Values

```
SELECT ID, table1.intValue * Val.N, date
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN (VALUES (5), (10), (15)) Val(N)
```

Comment: I used your answer to fit my needs the best, and I feel it answers this question the most simply/accurately.

Answer (score 1):

This solution only uses a single `union`, rather than unioning the table to itself:

```
WITH    numbers
          AS ( SELECT   5 AS n
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   n + 5
               FROM     numbers
               WHERE    n + 5 <= 15
             )
    SELECT  id ,
            intValue + n AS intValue ,
            date
    FROM    numbers
            CROSS JOIN your_table
```

This solution is limited to providing sequences that can be expressed mathematically. However, it's advantage is that with only a little adaptation the number of values provided at run-time via a variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.intValue*5*B.number intValue, A.[date]
FROM YourTable A
CROSS JOIN (SELECT *
            FROM master.dbo.spt_values
            WHERE type = 'P'
            AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 3) B
```